# Node.js приложение запустить на хостинге

Tags: node.js, веб-сервер, хостинг

Написал сайт на Node+react+mongo. Соответственно все делал на локале (Запуск сервера и коддинг). Теперь взял пробное место на хостинге Timeweb. Залил туда проект, установил на сервере Node + все зависимости проекта. Код работает если вызываю команду `node app.js`, который запускает этот код

```js
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
// const path = require('path');
// const logger = require('morgan');
// const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('./config/db');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

const dirname = __dirname;

MongoClient.connect(db.url, (err, database) => {

    if (err) return console.log(err)
    require('./server/routes')(app, database, dirname);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => { console.log(process.env.PORT || port) })

})
```

и выводит в консоль соответствующий порт `8000`.
Вопрос собственно в том, как мне сделать чтобы мое приложение запускалось и все рендерилось под доменом так же как я это видел на локале.

Можно хотябы ссылку на какуюто информаию или туториал.

Comment: А домен у вас какой?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Зависит от того, что у вас там за сервер. Для nginx делать так:

1. Для начала сам nginx установить `sudo apt-get -y install nginx`.
2. Открыть конфиг файл `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` и написать там:

   ```
   server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  имя_вашего_домена;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Перезапустить nginx `sudo service nginx restart`.
4. Остаётся только в настройках DNS вашего домена направить его на ip этого сервера.

Comment: Домен у меня тестовый, с логином и сабдоменом.
Попробовал шаманить 100 разными командами и оно заработоло на правильном порту)
Но с этого всего появился следующий вопрос. Как сделать чтобы сайт не отображался по адресу с портом mydomen.ru:8000 а просто mydomen.ru?

Comment: Если настроите nginx как я описал, то сможете обращаться просто по mydomen.ru. Если речь о локальной машине, то запускайте свой nodejs сервер на 80 порту.

Comment: И небольшой совет: настраивайте локальное окружение точно так же, как на сервере, чтоб проще тестировать было. Я бы рекомендовал у себя локально nginx поднять.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!) В следующий раз учту это. Это просто мой первый проект на node.js, многих нюансов еще не знаю. Извините, к сожалению не могу проголосовать за ответ так как скилл тут еще маленький)

Comment: @Dimmi все мы когда-то были новичками. Будут ещё вопросы, спрашивайте ^_^